# Moving files from one dir to the new dir. Removing unneeded subfolders when replicating file path?

Tags: python, shutil

Im trying to move files inside source_dir that has a folder structure  like (folder>AAAA>03-03-2023>file.txt). I want to move the AAAA Folder and the file.txt to the new  destination (dest_dir). Right now my code is basically replicating my original folder structure and moving the .txt and that's fine but I just want to remove the sub folder inside the AAAA folder. How can I do this?

```
import os
import shutil


source_dir = "folder\\"
dest_dir = "newfolder\\"
        
    txt_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.txt')]
    if txt_files:
        # create the destination directory path
        rel_dir = os.path.relpath(root, source_dir)
        dest_subdir = os.path.join(dest_dir, rel_dir)
        # create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
        os.makedirs(dest_subdir, exist_ok=True)
        # move the files to the destination directory while preserving the directory structure
        for file in txt_files:
            src_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            dest_file = os.path.join(dest_subdir, file)
            shutil.move(src_file, dest_file)
            print(f"Moved file {file} to {dest_subdir}")
        # stop looking inside this folder and its subdirectories
        dirs.clear()
```

Edit: Adding the .replace code and giving the string name of the subfolder, removes the subfolder. This is great but is there a way for the code to handle it without giving a predefined string?

```
      rel_dir = os.path.relpath(root, source_dir)
      dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, rel_dir).replace('03-03-2023', '')
        os.makedirs(dest_path, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this. Just added this code.

old code:

```
        rel_dir = os.path.relpath(root, source_dir)
        dest_subdir = os.path.join(dest_dir, rel_dir)
```

new code:

```
if os.path.sep in rel_dir:
         rel_dir = rel_dir.split(os.path.sep)[0]
        dest_subdir = os.path.join(dest_dir, rel_dir)
```

I was trying to remove folders after file had moved. But was a lot better to handle and remove subfolders during file moving.